# Mutating a column in R from a particular row subset

Tags: r, dataframe, mutate

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe based upon three other columns: a parent column, specific indicator column, and the value of the combined parent-specific indicator.

Given:

```
  parent specific val
1      a        x  10
2      a        y  11
3      a        z  12
4      b        x  20
5      b        y  21
6      b        z  22
7      c        x  30
8      c        y  31
9      c        z  32
```

I'm looking to create a new column, say px_val (selecting the x value of each parent), so that the resulting dataframe is:

```
  parent specific val px_val
1      a        x  10     10
2      a        y  11     10
3      a        z  12     10
4      b        x  20     20
5      b        y  21     20
6      b        z  22     20
7      c        x  30     30
8      c        y  31     30
9      c        z  32     30
```

Code for test df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  parent=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'),
  specific=c('x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
  val=c(10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32)
)
```

I've thought to maybe iterate over the dataframe, storing the x value of a given parent in a variable and assigning that to each parent. But it feels like there has to be a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do it this way:

`px_val` will contain values where `specific` equals `x` for each unique parent -> `val[specific == 'x']`

`.by=...` groups only for this mutate, the advantage is that we do not need a ungroup() thereafter:

```
library(dplyr) #>= dplyr 1.1.0

df %>%
  mutate(px_val = val[specific == 'x'], .by=parent)

  parent specific val px_val
1      a        x  10     10
2      a        y  11     10
3      a        z  12     10
4      b        x  20     20
5      b        y  21     20
6      b        z  22     20
7      c        x  30     30
8      c        y  31     30
9      c        z  32     30
```

Comment: Thanks for this! hitting an error: 
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `px_val = val[specific == "x"]`.
✖ `px_val` must be size 9 or 1, not 3.

Comment: You have two options: 1. `df %>% 
  group_by(parent) %>% 
  mutate(px_val = val[specific == 'x']) %>% 
  ungroup()` 2. Update dplyr -> `install.packages("dplyr)"`